# SELECT * INTO statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to use this statement SELECT * INTO new_table FROM old_table but it's giving me the error of undeclared value. I wanted to create a back table from one existing table to another new table.

Do I have first to create another table? or am I missing something.

the link below shows that the same statement can be used, so I don't why it's not working for me

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: Provide complete and unchanged query text and error message text.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `INSERT ... SELECT` statement for MySQL instead.

```sql
INSERT INTO new_table
  SELECT *
  FROM old_table
```

But `new_table` must exist. If you have MySQL version >= 8.0.19, then you can use instead the following syntax:

```sql
INSERT INTO new_table TABLE old_table;
```

You may check [13.2.6.1 INSERT ... SELECT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html).

### Background information

- The [`SELECT...INTO` is not exactly standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_syntax#:%7E:text=some%20non-standard%20implementations), it has selective support by vendors.
- [The statement does exist in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html), but is used for "query result to be stored in variables or written to a file".